# Expected unqualified-id before 'int'

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make an Arduino library, for a build that I'm going to be using throughout a few sketches, and I haven't been able to figure out why I keep getting this error. Searching on multiple forums, comes up with no working answers. This is my code:

charLCD.h:

```
#ifndef charLCD
#define charLCD

#include "Arduino.h"
class charLCD
{
  public:
    charLCD(int pin1,int pin2,int pin3,int pin4,int enable);
    void sendChar(unsigned char c);

  private:
    int _pin1;
    int _pin2;
    int _pin3;
    int _pin4;
    int _enable;



};
#endif
```

charLCD.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "charLCD.h"
#include <limits.h>
charLCD::charLCD(int pin1,int pin2,int pin3,int pin4,int enable) {
  _pin1 = pin1;
  _pin2 = pin2;
  _pin3 = pin3;
  _pin4 = pin4;
  _enable = enable;

}

void sendChar(unsigned char c) {
    // Send char to item
}


char* chartobin ( unsigned char c )
{
    static char bin[CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
    int i;

    for ( i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        bin[i] = (c % 2) + '0';
        c = c/2;
    }

    return bin;
}
```

The problem is on the line where I define the constructor in the header.

Comment: `char charLCD::*chartobin` looks wrong. Should that be `char* charLCD::chartobin`? Can't be sure since that function isn't declared in your header (though it would work with the `return` statement)

Comment: you declared `sendChar` as member of `charLCD` but then you define a free funcion of the same name. You did not declare `charLCD::chartobin` in the header

Comment: in which line is the error?

Comment: Defining preprocessor macros with the same name as your class is not going to end well.

Comment: @tobi303 on the line where I define the constructor in the header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of

```
#define charLCD
```

this is what your compiler sees:

```
class
{
  public:
    (int pin1,int pin2,int pin3,int pin4,int enable);
    void sendChar(unsigned char c);

  private:
    int _pin1;
    int _pin2;
    int _pin3;
    int _pin4;
    int _enable



};

::(int pin1,int pin2,int pin3,int pin4,int enable) {
  _pin1 = pin1;
  _pin2 = pin2;
  _pin3 = pin3;
  _pin4 = pin4;
  _enable = enable;

}

// ...
```

Pick a better header guard.

You also need to qualify the definitions of member functions:

```
void charLCD::sendChar(unsigned char c) {
    // Send char to item
}
```

Comment: It worked, although there were also some more small mistakes that I fixed.